# SpringData JPA Repository Method Query with a like?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

In Spring-data JPA, is there anyway to create a method query that is essentially searches by like??

I have the following method query

```
public MakeModel findByModelIgnoreCase(String model);
```

What I really want is a like expression. Do I need to just create a Criteria or a @Query annotation? Am I asking too much?

```
   //Stupid example of what I want to be able to do

    public MakeModel findByFuzzyModelIgnoreCase(String model);
```

Really I guess at the heart of it, I want to do a table search. I'm using Hibernate underneath Spring Data so I guess I could use some search api like Hibernate Search. I'm open to recommendations here.

Comment: JPQL has LIKE: https://blogs.oracle.com/JPQL01/entry/how_to_use_like_expression

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

Comment: axtavt that is exactly what I needed...

Comment: axtavt... that is exactly what I needed right there... You should put that in an answer... any feedback on a search api?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Like is supported too:

```
MakeModel findByModelLikeIgnoreCase(String model);
```

When you call the method use the follwing: 
Add `"%"` at the start to say that it doesn't matter to be a strict start match , 
the same at the end, or you can use one of them it depends on the like you want.

```
MakeModel makeModel = findByModelLikeIgnoreCase("%"+model+"%");
```

if your make model Is `test` and the string to compare to is `"%"+model+"%"` then :

```
es is a match , T is a match , test is a match
```

the string to compare to is `model+"%"`:

```
te is a match , es is not .
```

Comment: Great answer! You might wanna mention the `Containing`/`Contains` keywords that do the same but don't require the client to be aware of the like syntax for the particular store.

Answer (score 28):

If you don't want add "%" manually, you can use the following query methods:

```
MakeModel findByModelStartingWithIgnoreCase(String model); //SQL => LIKE 'model%'
MakeModel findByModelEndingWithIgnoreCase(String model); //SQL => LIKE '%model'
MakeModel findByModelContainingIgnoreCase(String model); //SQL => LIKE '%model%'
```

Comment: 1 small detail, IgnoreCase => ILIKE